# C Automatic Variables and Memory Addreses

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

I am being asked a question in a course and I am unsure if I am approaching the problem correctly.  We we're instructed to edit a C file to add in printf() statements to print both variable values and values of pointers to the variables where indicated.  The comments below were the indication of what we were supposed to do, and the subsequent code was my work.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a = 0x13579753;
static int b = 0x24680864;

void foobar(int, int, int *, int *);

int main(void)
{
    static int c = 0xaaaa5555;
    int d = 0x5555aaaa;
    int *ap = &a;
    int *bp = &b;
    int *cp = &c;
    int *dp = &d;
    int array[1] = {0x01010101};

    /* add code here to print the address of array[0]  */
    printf("Automatic Variable array[0] = %p\n", &array[0]);

    /* add code here to print the variables a, b, c, d and pointers  */
    printf("Variable a = %x\n",a);
    printf("Variable b = %x\n",b);  
    printf("Variable c = %x\n",c);  
    printf("Variable d = %x\n",d);

    printf("Pointer to Variable a = %p\n",ap);
    printf("Pointer to Variable b = %p\n",bp);
    printf("Pointer to Variable c = %p\n",cp);
    printf("Pointer to Variable d = %p\n",dp);

    /* add code here to print array[i] for i = 0 to high enough value */
    int i;
    for ( i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        printf("Value of array[%d] = %x\n",i, array[i]);

    /* call subroutine foobar and pass arguments  */
    foobar(a, d, &a, &d);

    return;
}

void foobar(int x, int y, int *xp, int *yp)
{
    int array[1] = {0x10101010};

    printf("Entering foobar\n");

    /* add code here to print address of array[0]  */
    printf("array[0] = %p\n", &array[0]);

    /* add code here to print array[i] for i = 0 to high enough value */
    int i;
    for ( i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        printf("Value of array[%d] = %x\n",i, array[i]);    

    return;
}
```

The instruction was then that we should see that as automatic variables are allocated memory that the addresses of the locations in memory should be decreasing.  I know variable "a" is not automatic, since it is external to a function.  I also know "b" is not automatic, since it is static, same with c.  Variable "d" is automatic, as are all of the 4 pointers to a,b,c,d.

So, should I be seeing that if I look at the memory addresses for "d" and then the 4 pointers the memory addresses should be decreasing?

I don't seem to be seeing this.

Any help is appreciate.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: All pointers to be printed with `%p` should be cast to `void *`. Usually failing to do this will not cause a problem, but it is technically required for the behavior to be defined by the C standard.

Comment: It is bad to teach that automatic objects are allocated descending addresses. You should **not** expect this behavior. The C implementation is free to allocate objects in any way it pleases, and various optimizations (notably arranging for efficient use of space given alignment requirements) will change the order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of your confusion is that you're looking at the values of the pointers, not the addresses of the pointers themselves... so you're only looking at the address of a single automatic variable. If you were to replace your pointer printfs with:

```
printf("Pointer to Variable a = %p\n",&ap);
```

(note `&ap`) the results would be what you're expecting. Note though that the order may or may not be in order of how you defined the variables; that's up to the compiler.

Comment: Thanks, I had this initially as well, but hedged because I wasn't't seeing this memory address decrease.  Oh well.